# win 7 can't paint combobox

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox, backcolor

I have my program that paint the backcolor of a combobox column in a datagridview.
I win xp everything works fine, but in win 7 the comboboxes have the gray color:
[image]

if you look the shot, you see that the combobox columns are grayed, but they must be yellow like the other columns.

if I use the old windows theme the grid is ok, but I wish use the new themes of win 7.

(i'm the developer, so I can change the code to paint the cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved, use flat style for the combobox and the color is shown correctly

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I hope someone comes up with a better solution, surely companies creating custom skins have this problem. There are the two solutions I found, either change the visual style or changing the FlatSyle;

[Possible to use XP Visual Style in Vista/Win7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000187/possible-to-use-xp-visual-style-in-vista-win7)

[Need to change DatagridviewCombobox cell background color in Windows7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/fa259b08-5ccc-4c33-bfc2-7f929f44c965/)

Although this talks about the ForeColor, it may be also provide a fix for the backcolor;

[How to change ForeColor of ComboBox's Selected Item? @Cody Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312825/how-to-change-forecolor-of-comboboxs-selected-item/5320865#5320865)